# Android Cocos2d-x 3.0: how to get Application Context in cocos2d-x?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, android-context

In Cocos2d-x2.x I use JNI to get Application Context in MainActivity `onCreate` function, however , this function had been removed scenes cocos2d-x3.0,so how can I get android Application context in cocos2d-x 3.0?

I found this function in main.cpp. but I'm not sure if the `thiz` parameter is the application context that I want?

```
void cocos_android_app_init (JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz) {
    LOGD("cocos_android_app_init");
    AppDelegate *pAppDelegate = new AppDelegate();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways:

1. Use Cocos2dxActivity.getContext()
2. Use static variable to store context such as:

> private static Activity instance;

Refer [this](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/jni-sending-a-android-content-context-parameter-to-a-function/2314/4).